# PCサイトをスマートフォンで見るときの設定について

Tags: css

お世話になります。

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、
スマートフォンでPCサイトを見る時に指でサイズを拡大・縮小できます。それを固定にする（拡大・縮小をできなくする）にはどのような設定が必要になるかお教えいただけませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

生成される HTML 中に

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

を埋め込めばできそうな気がします（いやオイラはガラケの人なので確認してません）

ですが、「できる」ことと「やっていい」ことは違います。
http://2ndidea.com/accessibility/pros-cons-of-user-scalable-no/
でも指摘されていますが、高齢者等視力の落ちた人に対して「拡大するな」は酷すぎです。
UX として論外でしょう。オイラならデザインレビューの段階でダメ出しします。
再考慮を強く推奨します。

Comment: 774RR様　助かりました。ピンポイントの回答でございました。事情があり、スマートフォンサイトを作るのではなく、pcサイトをスマートフォンサイト用に調整しなければなりませんでした。ちょっとややこしいですが。いずれにせよ、ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したのなら解決チェックしていただけると幸いです。なお IOS10 の Safari ではこの機能が無効化されていますので念のため。 `viewport` 関連の指定は `user-scalable` 以外にもいっぱいあるので要求に合うものを指定してくださいね。